# Slicing n-dimensional numpy array using list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a 3 dimensional numpy array:

```
np.random.seed(1145)
A = np.random.random((5,5,5))
```

and I have two lists of indices corresponding to the 2nd and 3rd dimensions:

```
second = [1,2]
third = [3,4]
```

and I want to select the elements in the numpy array corresponding to

```
A[:][second][third]
```

so the shape of the sliced array would be `(5,2,2)` and

```
A[:][second][third].flatten()
```

would be equivalent to to:

```
In [226]:

for i in range(5):
    for j in second:
        for k in third:
            print A[i][j][k]

0.556091074129
0.622016249651
0.622530505868
0.914954716368
0.729005532319
0.253214472335
0.892869371179
0.98279375528
0.814240066639
0.986060321906
0.829987410941
0.776715489939
0.404772469431
0.204696635072
0.190891168574
0.869554447412
0.364076117846
0.04760811817
0.440210532601
0.981601369658
```

Is there a way to slice a numpy array in this way? So far when I try `A[:][second][third]` I get `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2` because the `[:]` for the first dimension seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Numpy uses multiple indexing, so instead of `A[1][2][3]`, you can--and should--use `A[1,2,3]`.

You might then think you could do `A[:, second, third]`, but the numpy indices are *broadcast*, and broadcasting `second` and `third` (two one-dimensional sequences) ends up being the numpy equivalent of `zip`, so the result has shape `(5, 2)`.

What you really want is to index with, in effect, the outer product of `second` and `third`.  You can do this with broadcasting by making one of them, say `second` into a two-dimensional array with shape (2,1).  Then the shape that results from broadcasting `second` and `third` together is `(2,2)`.

For example:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: a = np.arange(125).reshape(5,5,5)

In [10]: second = [1,2]

In [11]: third = [3,4]

In [12]: s = a[:, np.array(second).reshape(-1,1), third]

In [13]: s.shape
Out[13]: (5, 2, 2)
```

Note that, in this specific example, the values in `second` and `third` are sequential.  If that is typical, you can simply use slices:

```
In [14]: s2 = a[:, 1:3, 3:5]

In [15]: s2.shape
Out[15]: (5, 2, 2)

In [16]: np.all(s == s2)
Out[16]: True
```

There are a couple very important difference in those two methods.

- The first method would also work with indices that are not equivalent to slices. For example, it would work if `second = [0, 2, 3]`.  (Sometimes you'll see this style of indexing referred to as "fancy indexing".)
- In the first method (using broadcasting and "fancy indexing"), the data is a *copy* of the original array.  In the second method (using only slices), the array `s2` is a view into the same block of memory used by `a`.  An in-place change in one will change them both.

Comment: Doing s2 = a[:, [1,2], [3,4]] doesn't work as you state, but instead of doing the outer product (which might become more complicated if you have more dimensions to think through) is there a reason why not to use a sequence such as: s2 = a[:, [1,2], :], s2 = s2[:, :, [3,4]]? (I know this is old thread)

Comment: Hi, sorry for bringing up old thread. Just wondering if in addition to the code-style, is there any performance difference between `A[1][2][3]` and `A[1. 2, 3]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
>>> out = A[np.ix_(range(A.shape[0]),second, third)]
>>> out.shape
(5, 2, 2)
>>> manual = [A[i,j,k] for i in range(5) for j in second for k in third]
>>> (out.ravel() == manual).all()
True
```

Downside is that you have to specify the missing coordinate ranges explicitly, but you could wrap that into a function.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for! Thank you. Definitely think this should be accepted answer as it is the most generally applicable.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are three problems with your approach:

1. Both `second` and `third` should be [`slices`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice)
2. Since the 'to' index is exclusive, they should go from `1` to `3` and from `3` to `5`
3. Instead of `A[:][second][third]`, you should use `A[:,second,third]`

Try this:

```
>>> np.random.seed(1145)
>>> A = np.random.random((5,5,5))                       
>>> second = slice(1,3)
>>> third = slice(3,5)
>>> A[:,second,third].shape
(5, 2, 2)
>>> A[:,second,third].flatten()
array([ 0.43285482,  0.80820122,  0.64878266,  0.62689481,  0.01298507,
        0.42112921,  0.23104051,  0.34601169,  0.24838564,  0.66162209,
        0.96115751,  0.07338851,  0.33109539,  0.55168356,  0.33925748,
        0.2353348 ,  0.91254398,  0.44692211,  0.60975602,  0.64610556])
```

Comment: On closer inspection, I think I misunderstood the question: `second` and `third` are not supposed to be ranges, but you want exactly those indices -- a bit misleading, using consecutive indices, though. I'll still leave this as an answer here, for completeness.